# how to pass array of object in Javascript to C# mvc5 model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

is there a way to pass an array of object and then assign it to model?

i searched that making the same variable name in your model and object will do the work but it doesn't work for me.

the model always get null values.

```
var answers = [];
var answerOthers = [];
var comment = $("#message").val();

$("input:radio:checked").each(function () {
    var questno = $(this).attr("data-question");
    var ansid = $(this).val();

    answers.push({ QUESTIONID: questno, ANSWERID: ansid});

    if ($(this).val() == 3)
    {
        var txtOther = $("#otherTxt-" + $(this).attr("data-question")).val();
        answerOthers.push({
            QUESTIONID: questno,
            ANSWER: txtOther
        });
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'insertQuestions',
    data: { answers: answers, answer_others: answerOthers, userid: userid   , comment: comment },
    method: 'GET',
    success: function ()
    {
        alert("saved");
    },
    error: function (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

c# controller

```
  public void insertQuestions(List<ratingsModel.ANSWERS> answers,
        List<ratingsModel.ANSWERS_OTHERS> answer_others, int userid , string comment)
    {
        insertAnswers(answers,userid);
        insertAnswer_others(answer_others, userid);

        MySqlConnection myconn2 = new MySqlConnection(cmn.connstring);
        myconn2.Open();
        string query3 = "INSERT INTO comments (userid,comment) VALUES" +
                       " (@userid,@comment)";
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query3, myconn2);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myconn2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: thanks that works for me.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You could add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with a GET (the data you pass to the method would need to be a query string and to represent your collections you need individual name/value pairs with collection indexers, for example

```
data { [0].QUESTIONID: xx, [0].ANSWERID: yy  [1].QUESTIONID: zz, .... etc }
```

But it should not be a GET in any case. Your method is changing data so it should be a POST (and in addition, if your collections were large, your would exceed the query string limit and throw an exception)

Change the ajax code to

```
$.ajax({
    url: @Url.Action('insertQuestions'), // dont hard code your url's
    data: JSON.stringify({ answers: answers, answer_others: answerOthers, userid: userid, comment: comment }) // modify,
    contentType: 'application/json', // add
    method: 'POST', // change
    success: function() {
        ....
```

As a side note, if you had generated your form correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods, then you code could simply have been

```
$.ajax({
    url: @Url.Action('insertQuestions'), 
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    method: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        ....
```

and none of the code for generating the arrays would be required.